# Prevent space before publisher list in biblatex driver

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to write a custom driver for books (among other things), but I've run into a problem.

My current output is:

```
HI Dutton, The Patent System and Inventive Activity During the Industrial Revolution 1750-1852( Manchester University Press, 1984)
                                                                                              ^^
```

The expected output is:

```
HI Dutton, The Patent System and Inventive Activity During the Industrial Revolution 1750-1852 (Manchester University Press, 1984)
                                                                                              ^^
```

I can't see what in the code is making the space appear after the bracket, although I'm new to biblatex so I'm probably specifying something incorrectly.

My current code:

```
% Publishing information
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+edition+date}{%
  (\printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date})%
  \newunit}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{publisher+edition+date}}
```

That is based on existing code which I still don't entirely understand.

I get that `\setunit{\addcomma\space}` puts in a space, but what's the difference between `\addspace` and `\space`?

What does `\newblock` actually do?  The manual isn't entirely clear.

How should I be writing in constants (such as `(` and `)`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to 'hardcode' parentheses in your bibmacros.  See § 4.11.7.2 of the manual (my version is currently 2.5): it is essential reading for what you are trying to achieve.  A simple-minded implementation of your bibmacro would be:

```
% Publishing information
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+edition+date}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%        <-- added
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  }%                          <-- added
  \newunit}
```

Which should yield: '(publisher, edition, date)'.

`\space` is not a `biblatex` command.  Try changing the line

```
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
```

to

```
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space\space\space}%
```

to

```
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space\addspace\addspace}%
```

to see the difference in practice.

Someone else will explain `\newblock` better, but think of your bibliography entry as composed of discrete 'chunks', where `\newblock` marks the division between each chunk --- which is necessary, among other things, for `biblatex` to be able to track punctuation so cleverly.  On this, see §. 4.11.7.